# Removing a subset from a set

Tags: haskell

This may be trivial but I'm stuck on writing a function that removes a subset of a set from the set itself (finding it's complement).
My function is in the form:

```
removeSubset :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] 
removeSet [] ys = Just ys
removeSet --This is where I don't know how to remove the subset
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to Haskell.

Comment: What is the purpose of returning a `Maybe [a]` instead of a simple `[a]`?

Comment: You're right, I should just use an [a]

Comment: These are not sets, they are lists. If you want sets, you should use `Data.Set` because that will enforce actual set conditions (no order, no duplicate members) and supports faster operations, including `O(m*log(n/m+1)), m <= n` set difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to wrap result in Maybe, because you may always return empty List.

Easiest implementation is:

```
removeSet xs ys = filter (not . (`elem` xs)) ys
```

After eta reduce:

```
removeSet xs = filter (not.(`elem`xs))
```

For more code-golfing point-free (point-less) style, it may also be written as:

```
removeSet = filter.((not.).(flip elem))
```

For more direct solution using recursion you may always use:

```
removeSet _  []    = []
removeSet [] ys    = ys
removeSet xs (y:ys)= if element y xs then removeSet xs ys else y:removeSet xs ys
  where element x [] = False
        element x (l:ls) = if l == x then True else element x ls
```

Comment: `if foo then True else bar` is better written as `foo || bar`.